# Do Android ART and HotSpot behave differently in non-volatile variable visibility？

Tags: java, android, hotspot, happens-before, non-volatile

I tested the below piece of code on HotSpot and Android ART, but with different results.

On HotSpot, `MyThread` never gets the updated `isRunning`, it get `isRunning` = true always...
But when I test it on ART, `MyThread` can get the updated `isRunning` and exit loop normally...

As I know about java happens-before rule, an non-volatile is not visible across multi-thread, just like the behave of the code below on Hotspot.

Does it depends on VM implementation? Or maybe Android ART has their own optimization?

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread running");
        while (true) {
            if (isRunning == false) break;
        }
        System.out.println("MyThread exit");
    }
}

public class RunThread{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RunThread().runMain();
    }

    public void runMain() {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        try {
            thread.start();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            thread.isRunning = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "`MyThread` never gets the updated `isRunning`, it get `isRunning = true` always..." - Or the compiler optimized out the `while(true)` which has no side effect (like calling the function or accessing volatile variable). That is you have conditional loop `if(isRunning == false) while(true);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> an non-volatile is not visible across multi-thread, just like the behave of the code below on Hotspot.

That's not *quite* right.  A non-volatile write, absent any additional synchronization or other happens-before relationship, is not *guaranteed* to be visible to a read of that same variable in another thread.  It's *allowed* to be visible, though.  I've absolutely seen HotSpot make writes visible across threads despite no happens-before relationship.  Based on my experience with this, I suspect that if you remove that `Thread.sleep` call in your code, HotSpot will also make the write to `isRunning` visible to the thread, despite the lack of any happens-before relationship between the write and the read.

You're definitely right that it's VM-specific, and it's possibly/likely even processor architecture–specific, since different architectures may give different amounts of synchronization for "free", or have different amounts of cache that affect whether a memory address is read from a core's cache or fetched from main memory.

In summary, you should never rely on this sort of behavior working any specific way on any specific VM—it's liable to change without warning.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, I think I basically understand this question.

Comment: Glad it helped! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you think it answers the question so that others can find it more easily.